# How are exceptions handled in Weblogic 12c?

Tags: java, exception, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic8.x

We are upgrading Oracle Weblogic server 8.1 to Weblogic Server 12c and java 1.4 to 1.8

I have the task to secure that app functionality stays intact. Some apps aren't touched since 2007.

There's the previous code:

```
if (e.getCause() instanceof java.net.ConnectException 
                || e.getCause() instanceof weblogic.utils.net.SocketResetException
                || e.getCause() instanceof weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException
                || e.getCause() instanceof javax.ejb.EJBException) {...}
```

searching for the "weblogic.jar" (found it at "\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib" I see that it has no classes. And looking in "wlclient.jar" I see it has a bunch of classes but not those from above.

Do you know how this exceptions are caught on WLS 12c? Is there a new type/class?

Comment: which version of 12c ? in 12.1.3: /Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/features/weblogic.server.merged.jar /Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/wlthint3client.jar etc. weblogic.jar it's a wrapper pointing to other jar's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment of devwebcl I went looking around the jars at "Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\" and all its sub-folders.

We are using WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.3.0
Founded the needed classes in:
..\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\modules\com.bea.core.utils.full.jar
..\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\modules\com.bea.core.weblogic.rmi.client.jar